# Preloading local Image assets in Flutter to display without delay

Tags: image, flutter, preload

What exactly is the right way to preload local Image Assets in Flutter? I have tried the `precache()` function but the image still delays before it displays on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this issue from the Flutter repo:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70527

Shortly, you might find delays:

- for the size of your images,
- in debug mode, performances are slower, try with `--release` mode
- the stable channel might be slower than master
- your system might be slow running the development environment

In the link above you can find some simple examples and how they have different response from different developers.

Once the images are loaded the first time there should be no delay.

Comment: possibly, to avoid the flashing effect of the first time loading you can use FadeInImage widget:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html